# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression. jQuery + Php Issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm sure the issue is simple and I'm just being ignorant and can't figure it out.

I have a profile feed on my website that allows users to post a status which appears instantly using jquery's ajax function.

When trying to post the html that is what jquery is saying the error is, that the entire html for the new post row is the syntax error. However, if I remove all the html and just have the actual post's text appear instead of html, it still gives me the error.

This is the javascript:

```
    $('body').on('click','.submit_feed',function () {

    var post = $("#feed_content").val();
    var hidden_id = $("#hidden").val();

    $("#loading").fadeIn("slow");

    if( content.length < 4)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/matthew/xaos/users/ajax/feed",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                parent: hidden_id,
                content:post
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#feed_error').html($(data).hide().fadeIn('slow'));
                $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
            }
        });
        $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#feed_error').remove();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/matthew/xaos/users/ajax/feed",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                parent: hidden_id,
                content:post
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#feed').prepend($(data).hide().fadeIn('slow'));
                $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
                $("input[type='text']").val('');
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

As you can see it requests interaction with users/ajax/feed which is what inserts the data into the database and returns back the html.

This is the php I use:

```
    $return['user']     = user_lib::find_user($this->user['user_id']);
    $return['content']  = $this->input['content'];

    if( isset( $this->input['content'] )  )
    {
        if( strlen( trim( $this->input['content'] ) ) < 4 )
        {
            print '<h6>Post must be more than 4 characters</h6>';
            exit();
        }
        $previous_feed = $this->db->fetch_row("select feed_id from user_feed order by feed_id desc");
        if( ! $previous_feed )
        {
            $previous_feed['feed_id'] = 0;
        }

        $insert['feed_id']      = $previous_feed['feed_id'] + 1;
        $insert['feed_parent']  = $this->input['parent'];
        $insert['feed_user']    = $this->user['user_id'];
        $insert['feed_date']    = time();
        $insert['feed_content'] = $this->input['content'];

        $return['feed_id'] = $this->db->insert('user_feed', $insert );

        $html = <<<HTML
        <table style="border:solid 1px #d7d7d7;margin-bottom:5px;">
            <tr>
                <td class="row2" style="width:1%;">{$data['avatar']}</td>
                <td class="row1" style="width:100%;" valign="top">
                    <p>{$return['user']}</p>
                    <p>{$return['content']}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
HTML;

        @header( "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8" );
        print $html;
        exit();
    }
```

When I remove all of the html and just do print $return['content']; or print $this->input['content'] no error occurs in the browsers console log but it doesn't return any text to the #feed id that is is meant to.

If any additional information is required please let me know.

Any ideas on what's going on would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you see coming back as the response in your net panel?

Comment: What I titled the issue as: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: html code in $html

Comment: No, thats the javascript error from the console. If you switch to the net panel you can actually see the HTTP response. Im guessing somehting is going wrong and producing an invalid response content, so when you do `$(data)` you get that error because its a bad selector/html snippet.

Comment: How can I switch to the net panel and see the actual HTTP response?
It's just weird, I have a shoutbox using the exact same code and that works fine. Everything seems to work until it's time to print the html.

Comment: If youre using Firebug then click on "Net" at the top of the firebug window. If youre using Chrome, then click on "Network" at the top of the Devtools panel. If youre using something else then you have issues :-)

Comment: Everything is fine in the network panel.

    `Request URL:http://localhost/matthew/xaos/users/ajax/feed
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:200 OK`

It shows me the html i want returned rendered and in raw format and it works there. I took off the if statement to simply my code and see if anything could be interfering and it's doing the same thing.  Any other ideas?